# Bash script in jenkins for signing application behaves wrong

Tags: bash, jenkins

I'm trying to set up Jenkins to build and deploy one of the applications I'm working on.
I created a stage where it signs the application.
It does sign the application, but immediately after it tries to execute the different options as separate commands.

```
13:07:16  + bash
13:07:16  + cd Wrap.UI
13:07:16  + 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x86\signtool.exe' sign /f './Service.pfx' /p password ./bin/x64/Test/Wrap.UI.exe
13:07:16  Done Adding Additional Store
13:07:16  Successfully signed: ./bin/x64/Test/Wrap.UI.exe

13:07:16  
13:07:16  Number of files successfully Signed: 1

13:07:16  Number of errors: 4

13:07:16  SignTool Error: File not found: F:/

13:07:16  SignTool Error: This file format cannot be signed because it is not recognized.
13:07:16  SignTool Error: An error occurred while attempting to sign: ./Service.pfx

13:07:16  SignTool Error: File not found: P:/

13:07:16  SignTool Error: File not found: password
```

The string in the Jenkins script looks like this

```
    sh '''
bash
                        cd Wrap.UI
                        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\bin\\10.0.19041.0\\x86\\signtool.exe" sign /f "./Service.pfx" /p password ./bin/x64/''' + CONFIGURATION + '''/Wrap.UI.exe
                        cd ..
                    '''
```

I apologies for the weird spacing in the code section.

I'm guessing here is I need to encapsulate the command with its parameters somehow, but I'm not very familiar with bash scripts and could use some help with that.

Comment: What is CONFIGURATION?

Comment: Nothing here seems to be related to Bash per se. It looks vaguely like maybe you are using some Windows wrapper which replaces slashes with backslashes (though even that doesn't really explain everything here). Also, what's with the lone `bash` as the first command? Did you mean to write `bash -c '...'` and forget to complete it?

Comment: CONFIGURATION is a jenkins variable

Comment: Well yes, but how is it defined?

Comment: to be honest I didn't write this initially, I copied this pattern from a previous stage that does the same thing but calls msbuild.exe and builds the application. I added this stage to sign the application afterwards.

Comment: it is defined in the jenkins script, environment {
        CONFIGURATION = 'Development'
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Windows, perhaps try to use a `bat` command instead of a `sh` command. (I never thought I was going to suggest this, but it looks like your `sh` support is buggy.)

```
bat """
    cd Wrap.UI
    "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\bin\\10.0.19041.0\\x86\\signtool.exe" sign /f "./Service.pfx" /p password ./bin/x64/${CONFIGURATION}/Wrap.UI.exe
"""
```

Notice also that there is no need to `cd ..` at the end; the command runs in a separate environment, and its current working directory will not be reflected back in the parent.

Tangentially, the lone `bash` wasn't doing anything useful. If you want to run a command in Bash instead of `sh`, the syntax for that is `sh '''bash -c 'commands; more commands'; '''`. But nothing here requires Bash; `cd` behaves the same in `bash` and `sh`, and besides that, you are just running an external Windows command.  The lone `bash` would start and exit an interactive Bash shell.

Comment: This worked. thank you! looks much cleaner as well. I will change all other locations that use the same pattern. was written by a previous developer, neither of us are good with bash scripts.